# can no longer unit test

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, yaml

I was following the resoCoder Clean Architecture tutorial yesterday and was able to execute a unit test. I meanwhile continued a bit and now can no longer unit test. I have found quite a few ideas on how to overcome this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462646/how-to-solve-not-found-dartui-error-while-running-integration-tests-on-flutt), but nothing so far works.

The answers suggest:

- use `test` package instead of `flutter_test` package. No matter what I include, I get version conflicts. And yesterday I WAS able to execute the unit tests with the `flutter_test` package
- In Run... select `tests in <file name>`. This leads to `Error: Entrypoint file not found at...`
- In Run... select `<file name>`. This leads to many errors of the kind `../../Applications/flutter%20env/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' import 'dart:ui';`

Any ideas what I may have broken? I noticed this when I created an own unit test and then checked that also yesterday's test (which ran successfully) no longer runs.

This is my according yaml section

```dart
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

  mockito: ^5.3.0
  build_runner: ^2.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a work around, however, I adapted the concept of the todo tutorial at bloclibrary, and separated the domain and the data layer as packages. Now I can test those with the test package and the presentation layer with the flutter_test package